# How to make all cakephp files to inner folder access from base?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

Currently my Cake structure is like below and is working fine

```
/public_html/app 
/public_html/.htaccess
/public_html/index.php
```

So that I can access **mydomain.com**  to my application.

I need to create new inner folder called `src` and put all files in public_html*.

Like `/public_html/*` to `/public_html/src/*`

```
/public_html/src/app 
/public_html/src/.htaccess
/public_html/src/index.php
```

I need to  access **mydomain.com** from src folder files.

I tried with creating an **htaccess** file `public_html/.htaccess`

**/public_html/.htaccess**

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ src/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) src/$1 [L]
```

and put all files in cake framework new inner folder `src`. It gives me an Internal Server Error.

Then I created a **index.php** file `public_html/index.php` and deleted htaccess(`public_html/.htaccess`) present in public_html.

**index.php**

```
define('SRC_DIR', 'src');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require SRC_DIR . DS . 'index.php';// src/index.php file
```

But It goes to page, but styles and images are not coming. Routes are not working.

**public_html** is base path.

How to make this correct in cakephp2 ?

Comment: @faa I need to access `http://domain.com/index.php` from `public_html/src/index.php`, not `http://domain.com/src/index.php` from `public_html/src/index.php`.

Comment: Why do you have a development style install on your site?

Comment: You want to access the app like it is installed in the root, but actually have CakePHP base files inside `src` folder?

Comment: @rlcabral Yes, absolutely that is my requirement. The entire framework will be inside `src` folder.

Comment: @AD7six I don't understand what you mean here. If you mean why `src` is used, then I need other parallel folders like `blah`,`bleu` with `src`. These folders('blah', 'bleu') have not relation with cake application. I need these folders directly accessed either by htaccess or else. If I add cake directly to root, then all files and folders looks like a messy(structure).

Comment: Please [read the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html).

Comment: @AD7six Are you saying to  set the DocumentRoot directive for the domain.

Comment: No, I'm asking _why_ you have a development-style install?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, I'll go ahead with an answer.

From what I understood, [Justin John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036917/justin-john) wants to access something like this:

```
mydomain.com           #access CakePHP
mydomain.com/blah      #access the folder blah
```

He wants to move CakePHP to `public_html/src` and create any sub-folder he needs in `public_html/`. Like this:

```
# THIS IS WRONG
/public_html
   /src             #CakePHP
      /app
      /lib
      /plugins
      /vendors
   /blah
   /another_folder
```

What you should do is put CakePHP installation in `public_html` and any sub-folder in the webroot folder.

```
# This is the Cake way
/public_html
   /app
      /webroot
         /blah
         /another_folder
   /lib
   /plugins
   /vendors
```

It is all explained in [the CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html) that [AD7six](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761202/ad7six) linked.

Comment: note that [you can configure the directory layout](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html) into any desired permutation - i.e. `app`, `webroot` and `lib/Cake` folders don't have to have this layout, they can be anywhere.